# how to parse JSON response using power shell?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook, invoke-webrequest

I'm looking for parsing JSON respoonse with powershell ruuning on azure runbook.,
The following is my code.

```
$servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"         
Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Write-Verbose

$uri = 'https://nseindia.com//emerge/homepage/smeNormalMktStatus.json'
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing
Write-Output $result
$result = $result.Content
Write-Output $result
Write-Output $result.NormalMktStatus
Write-Output 'saranaraj kumar'
# Stop-AzStreamAnalyticsJob -Name SQLCDCProcessor -ResourceGroupName RealTimeAnalytics
```

The following is my JSON response

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"NormalMktStatus":"open"}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    Content-Length: 26
                    Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
                    Content-Type: application/json
                    Date: Fri, 27 ...
Forms             : 
Headers           : {[X-FRAME-OPTIONS, SAMEORIGIN], [Pragma, no-cache], [Connection, keep-alive], [Content-Length, 
                    26]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : 
RawContentLength  : 26
{"NormalMktStatus":"open"}
saranaraj kumar
```

From power i'm getting JSOn reponse as above, I can read response.content that contains  `{"NormalMktStatus":"open"}`
but if I'm using `response.content.normalMKTstatus` I'm getting empty space.
how to resolve it?
And also I wanna do if-else condition with power shell that is

```
if(response.content.normalMKTstatus -eq 'open')
    {
    write-output true
    }
    else
    {
    write-output false
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `$result =`[`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)`...`, `$result.Content` contains a JSON *string* in your case, which you first need to parse into *objects* in order to be able to access properties with dot notation (`.normalMktStatus`).

While you could use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) to perform this parsing, **it is simpler to use the 
[`Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod), which performs the JSON parsing behind the scenes and directly returns an object (of type `[pscustomobject]`) representing the JSON content**:

```bsh
$obj = Invoke-RestMethod https://nseindia.com//emerge/homepage/smeNormalMktStatus.json

$obj.NormalMktStatus # -> 'open'

if ($obj.NormalMktStatus -eq 'open') {
  $true
}
else {
  $false 
}
```